# Detection of tomato areas from UAV images using ML

Tags: geotiff-tiff, machine-learning, bigtiff

I have many UAV .tif images which they contain tomato plant in a farm, and between them there is separation with soil. So by searching on google I have found this paper https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/13/7/1358 and this ML model: https://github.com/aipal-nchu/RiceSeedlingDataset#3-dataset-of-rice-seedling-detection that identifies rice plants and separates them from soil. I need to extend the idea and implement it on tomato areas in order to identify tomato plants and paint a square around them in order to separate them from soil. Each tomato area has around 50 tomato plants, around is the soil, and next to it another tomato plant then soil, etc..(I mean that I do not want the rectangle to consist of tomato units, but tomato areas). The problem is that I do not have dataset as the guy in the paper, but only enormous .tifs. My first thought was to take the .tifs I have and crop small areas in order to make a training dataset and a testing dataset. But it is too time consuming to generate I don't know, let's say 2000 images for training and 200 images for testing manually in order to make my ML model work.

Are there any more efficient way to make my training/testing dataset from the .tif images I have?

Update (15/12/2021):

After many days searching I tried this code: https://imageai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customdetection/#note-imageai-will-switch-to-pytorch-backend-starting-from-june-2021 . What I basically did is that I cropped and gathered about 600 smaller images from the 6 main UAV .tif image. Then I annotated all of them, so imagine that I have 600 images and 600 annotations. I splited the images to 20% validation and 80% training. This is the code:

```
from imageai.Detection.Custom import DetectionModelTrainer

trainer = DetectionModelTrainer()
trainer.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
trainer.setDataDirectory(data_directory="hololens")
trainer.setTrainConfig(object_names_array=["hololens"], batch_size=4, num_experiments=200, train_from_pretrained_model="pretrained-yolov3.h5")
trainer.trainModel()
```

What do I put here: `trainer.setTrainConfig(object_names_array=["hololens"],...`
instead of `hololens`?

I do not imagine I should put a list with the names of 600 (different) annotations.

Also do I need to crop 600 images from the 6 main UAV .tifs or should I annotate on the main UAV .tif image?

If yes, should I use the same name in every annotation on the main UAV .tif image?

This is the error I get:

```
2021-12-11 12:11:26.531733: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2/../../lib64:
2021-12-11 12:11:26.531803: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Generating anchor boxes for training images and annotation...
Average IOU for 9 anchors: 1.00
Anchor Boxes generated.
Detection configuration saved in  /small_test/json/detection_config.json
Evaluating over 0 samples taken /small_test/validation
Training over 258 samples  given at /small_test/train
Some labels have no annotations! Please revise the list of labels in your configuration.
Training on:    None
Training with Batch Size:  4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_code.py", line 20, in <module>
    trainer.trainModel()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/imageai/Detection/Custom/__init__.py", line 224, in trainModel
    print("Number of Training Samples: ", len(train_ints))
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know manual annotation is still needed in many machine learning models, and indeed is usually the most time consuming task. Also your question is really not a GIS problem and might get better answers on the main stackoverflow site.

Comment: Can I crop from the .tif files the parts that I want using QGIS?

Comment: @Shawn machine learning questions with a spatial component are indeed welcome here.

Comment: This is a classic feature extraction problem and relatively straightforward as long as the AOI contains homogeneous vegetation. As for generating a training set, I agree with @Shawn, that manually delineating and labelling your features of interest is the most time consuming part. Without seeing your dataset and AOI, I would consider : 1) tiling your AOI into manageable tiles, 2) randomly selecting n tile samples, 3) manually delineate and label the training set, 4) run the ML model.

Comment: Is there any fast way to cut from the .tif image the parts (AOI) I want and make them separate .jpeg files?? MSPaint is not a fast solution doing this work manually... :-)

Comment: You had a tag for Python but present no code so I have removed it.

Comment: Also, I would recommend transfer learning for your case if you can get the weights from the rice datasets. Essentially freeze the layers on a previously trained dataset (e.g. the rice dataset) and add new trainable layers on top of the frozen layers. Typically, this will reduce the number of training samples required. Here's an example: https://www.kaggle.com/hmendonca/airbus-mask-rcnn-and-coco-transfer-learning